# Creating multiprocess in a Python script and use it in another

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, multiprocessing, threadpool

Basically, I have a server in `Flask` that need to do a lot of comparison so I need to make them in parallel.
**My goal** is to create the pool of worker to make this comparisons when the server is starting.
After some time, a new information is added to the database and it use the worker pool to compare this new information to the all database.
Until now I didn't have any issue, but I handled the worker like this:

A function in a script `config.py` use a global variable `worker_pool` to create the workers when the server start

```py
worker_pool = None

def run():
    global worker_pool
    worker_pool = Pool(10)
```

In another script, I simply do this when a new infromation is added to the database:

```py
SimilarityComputed = config.worker_pool.map(self.compute_similarity_parallel, CrashToCompute)
```

where `CrashToCompute` is a list of my different comparisons formatting correctly

I'm not sure using a global variable for the workers is the best way to do it but I can't really give it as an argument.
Finally, I get this **error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 628, in run
    testMethod()
  File "...\src\Tests\CrashLogClassifierTests.py", line 17, in test_UpdateComputeSimilarity
    classifier.compute_all_similarity(db, True)
  File "...\src\CrashLogClassifier.py", line 70, in compute_all_crash_similarity
    self.add_crash_similarity_parallel(db, CrashToCompute, overwrite)
  File "...\src\CrashLogClassifier.py", line 100, in add_crash_similarity_parallel
    SimilarityComputed = config.worker_pool.map(self.compute_similarity_parallel, CrashToCompute)  # Sending the work to the pools, it sends the data by pairs of dictionaries
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'SequenceMatcher' object has no attribute 'matching_blocks'
```

If somebody has a better way to do this or a solution to this error, it would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `SequenceMatcher` is your code, right?  It’s saying that one of the `Pool`’s processes got the displayed exception.

Comment: No `SequenceMatcher` is an object of the Pool library